# Android - Set background color on user choice

Tags: java, android, if-statement, parse-platform

Lets say I have 4 options for a user, North, South, East and West (N,S,E,W). And depending on what option the user choses I want each direction to be linked with a color, and when a user picks a direction that they have to do I save that to my backend Parse.com and then set the background color of the entire app to the that is linked to the chosen direction.

Currently I am going about it like this:

```
if (currentUser.getString("direction").equals("north")) {
    //set background color to red
}
else if (currentUser.getString("direction").equals("west")) {
    //set background color to blue
}
else if (currentUser.getString("direction").equals("east")) {
    //set background color to black=
}
else if (currentUser.getString("direction").equals("south")) {
    //set background color to green
}
```

Which isn't too bad when there are just four options but I have just simplified this for this example if there are 100 options this is no longer a good option.

What would be another more efficient way of doing this?

The user doesn't pick a color, I want to link the direction to a color thats what I am trying to get at?

Thanks for the help in advance.

I am getting this compile error with the enum Direction:

[image]

Comment: You have to use Switch in this case. But you should in this case use integer values.

Comment: @FaroukTouzi a switch isn't much more efficient than if-statements for 100 cases

Answer (score 3):

You might use an [`enum` type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html). Something like,

```
enum Direction {
    NORTH(Color.RED), WEST(Color.BLUE), EAST(Color.BLACK), SOUTH(
            Color.GREEN);

    Direction(Color c) {
        color = c;
    }

    private Color color;

    public static Direction fromName(String name) {
        for (Direction d : Direction.values()) {
            if (d.name().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                return d;
            }
        }
        return NORTH;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }
}
```

Then, you can use it like

```
Direction.fromName("south").getColor(); // <-- green.
```

Comment: where do I get the users selected option from parse.com

Comment: I don't use parse.com; so I can't help you with that.

Comment: okay but then where do I input the selected value/ how do I call this?

Comment: Read the last line (of the answer) again.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use an android [TypedArray](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#TypedArray)?
You can for example use:

*res/values/arrays.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <array name="parse_colors">
        <item>#FFFF0000</item>
        <item>#FF00FF00</item>
        <item>#FF0000FF</item>
    </array>
</resources>
```

*src/MyActivity.java*

```
TypedArray parseColors = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array. parse_colors);
int currentUserBackgroundValue = currentUser.getInt("direction");
String hexColor = colors.getColor(currentUserBackgroundValue, 0); //the second value it's the default value

myView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(hexColor));
```

For consistency between parse server and your application consider to use `ParseConfig`, documentation [here](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#config)